# Getting data out of a JSON object in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to extract data from a JSON object by passing field names but then I get the undefined results when I try to extract data . For some reason the way I am getting the JSON Object is not the way I expected. What could be the error?

JS code -

```
  function initfunc() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "/dashboard",
                        data: JSON.stringify({country: country[counter], bankid: bankid[counter]}),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (Result) {
                            Result = Result.Resultset
                            // console.log("result", Result);


                            //  console.log("result",Result);
                            var data = [];
                            var merchantname = [];
                            var successtranscs = [];
                            var failedtranscs = [];
                            var servicetranscs = [];
                            var bankname;
                            console.log("result",Result);
                            for(var i in Result) {
                                merchantname.push(Result[i].MERCHANTNAME); // or .MERCHANTNAME?
                                successtranscs.push(Result[i].NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS); // or .NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS?
                                failedtranscs.push(Result[i].NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS); // or .NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS?
                                servicetranscs.push(Result[i].NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS); // or .NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS?
                                bankname = Result[i].BankName; // or .BankName?
                            }
                            //console.log("merchantname",merchantname);
                            StackedChart(bankname, merchantname, successtranscs, failedtranscs, servicetranscs);
                            merchantname = [];
                            successtranscs = [];
                            failedtranscs = [];
                            servicetranscs = [];
                            rows = null;
                            if (counter == country.length - 1) {
                                counter = -1;
                                counter++;
                            }
                            else {
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    });





                }
```

server.js -

```
app.post('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
    cnn.TransactionInfo(req.body.country,req.body.bankid, function (err, result) {
        var resultset = {"Result":result};
        console.log(resultset);

        res.send({ Resultset : resultset });


    });
});
```

Initial Result set from stored procedure - resultset-

```
{ Result:
   [ { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'MPesa',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 29,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 4 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'Zuku',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 1,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'BALANCE',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 21,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'AIRTEL',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 2,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'SAFARICOM',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 4,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'FIXEDDEPOSIT',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 1,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'FOREX',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 1,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'KITSA2P',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 1,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'STATEMENT',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 2,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 },
     { BankName: 'IM BANK',
       MERCHANTNAME: 'TRANSFER',
       NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS: 1,
       NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS: 0,
       NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS: 0 } ] }
```

This is what I get after sending the data to my client script - The resultset becomes -

```
result:
Object
Result
:
Array[9]
0
:
Object
BankName
:
"IM BANK"
MERCHANTNAME
:
"MPesa"
NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS
:
0
NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS
:
2
NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS
:
25
```

Comment: You pass in an object with a Resultset member containing an object with an array stored in a member called Result, so you likely want to change "Result = Result.Resultset" to "Result = Result.Resultset.Result", and likely name things a bit more distinctly.

Comment: do one thing either use toJSON() function or JSON.parse() , after that you can change your data in JSon . then you can extract it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this at the backend while sending data to frontend

```
res.json(resultset);
```

while receiving at frontend,

```
console.log("result",JSON.stringify(Result)); //to display in string format
```

also, you will get the data in the desired format to push it into arrays as you want

Answer (score 0):

USERS.JSON

```
{
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",       
      "id": 3
   }
}
```

Code

```
     var express = require('express');
            var app = express();
        var fs = require("fs");

    app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {


        console.log(data);
        res.end(data);
    });
})
```